# Disadvantages and advantages of dividing a table into subtables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

Suppose, I have a table of 100s of fields, which can be subdivided into many sub-tables, using public key foreign keys I can make connection of those tables.

```
table_a: field1, field2, field_3, field_3_sub_field1, field_3_sub_field2, ....field_100
```

Now either I can keep it as it is or I can create anather table `field3`:

```
field3: field_3_sub_field1, field_3_sub_field2,
```

and get a reduced `table_a`:

```
table_a: field1, field2, ....field_100, field_3_id
```

Now my question is what are the advantages and disadvantages of this?

Comment: Why'd you let your database get that big?  Normally 10-12 rows is approaching uncomfortable, and 20 is very large.

Comment: 100% agree with Makoto, the question can't be answered effectively as there is a bigger issue at hand

Comment: @Makoto: you meant "columns", right? And this is nonsense, of course. It is not a big deal at all for a table to have 300-500 columns (provided that this is what you need). Databases can handle it without problems. This case, however, does seem like there may be schema design errors here.

Answer (score 2):

Except for some specialist purposes, you should design your database schema along relational principles, making appropriate use of normalisation and constraints.

There may be situations where deviation from that may bring advantages, but it's practically impossible to give meaningful advice without knowing the exact situation. Generic advice on the topic is likely to be misleading.

Comment: from my understanding what you are trying to say is if `sub_table` is being called every time I need to call "table", in that case it does not bring any good, on the other hand if `sub_table` is not called often I call `table`, then keeping them separated is good idea. Is it?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the question is vague and hypothetical, and therefore not worth answering in its current form, and you should instead follow the principles of good relational database design.

Answer (score 1):

In a general case, I don't see any advantages in dividing your table into several tables.

However, in certains situations, for example if you know that for `field3` you will have some repetitive values (same `field3` and `field3_sub...` for several lines of your main table), then dividing your main table in several tables will allow you to win space by normalizing the data (i.e. in your `table_a`, several `field_3_id` will be identical and point to the same data).

You should be more specific about what you store in your table to have more precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would say that your disadvantage you want to do is not a good practice, if you know your table tends to grow **Divide and conquer**